# Has any terrestrial experiment been carried out which proves whether light can be thrown sideways or not?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, experimental-physics, photons

Let me stress, TERRESTRIAL EXPERIMENT, as distinct from astronomical observations of the transverse Doppler effect, stellar aberration and so on.

To clarify what I mean by 'thrown sideways'.  Supposing a source of light is moved in a straight line at 300 metres per second in a direction orthogonal to the direction of propagation.  Would the photons inherit the source's lateral movement so that they would take a path deviated by one part per million in the direction of the source's motion, from the direction they would have taken with the source stationary?

There are four possible answers to this question.

1. Yes.  The result was null.  Light can not be thrown sideways.
2. Yes.  The result was positive.  Light can be thrown sideways.
3. Yes, but practical difficulties prevented any definitive results from
    being obtained.
4. No. It is considered unnecessary to conduct such an experiment for the
    following reasons . . .

Which is it please?

Comment: Your experiment as described cannot be done. An experiment that will show the light-gravity interaction is proposed here since 2006 http://www.phys.uconn.edu/~mallett/Mallett2006.pdf , but I did not find that anybody has tried to do it."This paper has shown that the gravitational field produced by the cir-
culating light beam of a ring laser results in the rotation of the plane
of polarization of an electromagnetic wave. A laboratory arrangement has
been suggested"

Comment: While your question is experimental (and so I will leave the answer to the experts), it is based on the assumptions that challenge two most established theories, special relativity and quantum field theory. In relativity, the speed or direction of light does not depend on the movement of the source (only the energy does). In QFT, photons don't travel as particles on a definite path, but as waves of probability taking every available path at the same time. Thus your question is equivalent to asking if special relativity and QFT have been sufficiently tested and therefore is moot.

Answer (score 0):

[Foucault's apparatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizeau%E2%80%93Foucault_apparatus#Foucault's_determination_of_the_speed_of_light) uses a fast-rotating mirror to 'throw' light slightly sideways. The known rotational speed of the mirror plus the known distance that the light travelled was used to determine the speed of light.

Comment: would the accuracy of the experiment allow detecting gravitational effects?

Comment: @annav Faraday rotation?

Comment: just gave a link on the OP on a proposed experiment , in a comment

Answer (score 0):

On terrestrial length scales, any effect like that is so small that very special equipment is needed to measure it. However, the size of the effect can be greatly magnified by using distant stars instead of a light beam on earth. In this case, the "sideways propagation" effect can easily be measured with telescopes of the sort which have been available  for the last 100 years. It is named "stellar aberration"and has been extensively documented.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity of light is 10,000 times faster than the velocity of Earth. This means that when light travels 11 meters, the Earth moves 1.1 millimeters.

This 1.1 mm value would mean that in order to test whether or not stellar aberration applies to terrestrial light sources we would need to place a focused light source 1.1 mm ahead of the perfect ninety degree perpendicular position.

And assuming Earth to be in motion, and Bradley's aberration correct, we'd expect that the apparent position of this light source should shift forward like Gamma Draconis.

It should exhibit the same stellar aberration that we'd expect from a star. Stellar aberration assumes that the moving Earth intercepts the light that had left the star prior to the encounter. The telescope moves into position to 'catch' the light. The telescope on Earth moves into the path of the light so that it is perfectly perpendicular to it. And this is supposed to cause the shift of its apparent position forward.